# What language is in ".liquid" files?

Tags: shopify

I got some a small assignment to add a feature to a theme made on Shopify. I am good with PHP but shopify uses .liquid files.
I want to know how it works like this code snippet

```
{{% if payment.gateway | name %}}
```

Though they have given the documentation but I want to know how I can work on this language as I don`t have shopify paid version and I want to try this before paying for it.
Can anyone help me

Comment: It looks like some kind of template system

Answer (score 16):

It's Shopify's templating language, [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org).

You can sign up to the [Shopify Partner program](http://www.shopify.com/partners) and play with Liquid in a [dev shop](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/the-basics/build-your-theme/partners) for free.

[Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) also uses Liquid, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks I will try to see what is contains.

Answer (score 4):

Liquid is an open-source template language created by Shopify and written in Ruby. It is the backbone of Shopify themes.